# Tunnel from the internet to local network

Tags: python, c#, localhost, vpn, tunnel

What I would like to achieve:

1. Suppose we have computer `A` and `B` which are located on different local networks (e.g. both are laptops connected to home wi-fi via a router).
2. Computer `A` wants to have access to all devices connected to `B`'s wi-fi router, **and** to access the internet via the connection, which means `B` has to allow for `A`'s traffic to pass through his internet connection and return the responses back to `A`.

For example, someone with an IP address of `192.168.0.33` hosts a webpage on their machine on `B`'s local network (wifi router). `A` wants to access it, so `B` opens the tunnel into their local network, `A` connects to it and can browse the web page successfully.

I think the connection I'm trying to describe sounds familiar to `VPN`, but I'm not sure.

Are there any ready libraries/solutions for that kind of connection? Are there any resources that would hint how to create such a connection? Preferably, `C#` or `python`.

Comment: You can do this via a SSH Socks-Proxy.

Comment: @Hampus Larsson I've googled it, this seems to be the answer! https://ma.ttias.be/socks-proxy-linux-ssh-bypass-content-filters/

Comment: @Hampus Larsson maybe you happen to know a tool similar to ssh server for Windows? Isn't there a built in one?

Comment: I don't think that there is a built-in server for Windows. There should however be some freeware-servers around that should prove useful. Unfortunately, I have very little competence on the Windows-spectrum for that. Also, if you're looking to set up Socks-Proxies, then I would recommend you looking into a Firefox/Chrome plugin called "SwitchyOmega". In that plugin, you can setup rules that says what URLS / IP-adresses that you want to tunnel, and where to tunnel it (if you have multiple tunnels active).

Comment: @Hampus Larsson I think I might've found the library: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET . Looks promising, everything you mentioned seems to be there. Thanks for the hints, gonna try this one out!

Comment: You don't appear to state that either A or B can form a server that someone could connect into (eg via a port forwarding on their router) so I'm not quite sure how you propose to communicate across the NAT barrier (the pitch level of your question seems somewhat below what would be required for various NAT traversal techniques).. I'm curious though, if you do have the ability to eg create a port forwarding so A can access B, why bother with B at all; just forward to 0.33 and A can directly access the website

Comment: @Caius Jard good point there, didn't really think of forwarding the website itself, actually. What do you mean by NAT barrier? When I did port forwarding on my local machine with `netsh` from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`, my router was successfully able to forward the connection to my public ip address, even though I did not do any mapping settings to the router. I suppose, it's not the case for every router out there?

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/). It allows you to directly SSH to two systems on different networks.

In your case, if both `A` and `B` are on the same ZeroTier Network (Different Local Network), then you should be able to access any web server (website) hosted on `B` via `A` using ZeroTier.

ZeroTier Installation Instructions are given on the [Downloads Page](https://www.zerotier.com/download/). It has cross-platform support.

Comment: I wouldn't like to use a service which does the job of thinking for me, thank you very much

Comment: @winwin, I don't see the discussion in the comments speaking about developing this yourself. You are sharing GitHub links for Source Solutions that do the same thing. Since I use something similar personally, I shared. My Bad if it wasn't helpful. Be a bit clear on the question next time maybe?